# Inexplicable, simple, 'list index out of range' -- Python

Tags: python, django

I keep trying to use this for loop.  Actually a variety of for loops.  I keep getting the error, 'list index out of range'.  No idea.

```
for q in range(0, len(list(package_ids))-1):
        if (q==0):
            query = 'Zero' + package_ids[q]
        else:
            query = 'More' + package_ids[q]
```

Comment: what type is `package_ids`?

Comment: Why are you subtracting `1` from the `len(list(package_ids))` ?

Comment: It comes from a queryset that I applied .values('id') to

Comment: if for example there are 6 items in the list, it iterates up to 5 from 0

Comment: @mjabraham  But why do you think you need to subtract `1` ... are you not wanting to look at the last item?

Comment: i've actually tried it both ways @donkopotamus, I get the same result

Comment: @mjabraham If `package_ids` was a generator, then you just exhausted it by converting it to a list.  What is the type of `package_ids`?

Comment: Can show whats output of `print(package_ids)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its likely that `package_ids` is a generator, and the conversion to a list to find out the number of items has exhausted it, or perhaps its simply an iterable that does not expose `[]`.  In any case, your code would be better expressed as:

```
for q, x in enumerate(package_ids):
    if q == 0:
        query = 'Zero' + x
    else:
        query = 'More' + x
```

This will handle any type of iterable including a generator.

Or even more concise:

```
for q, x in enumerate(package_ids):
    query = ('More' if not q else 'Zero') + x
```

Comment: :-( I had tried that earlier as well.  Just tried it again for posterity.  Still getting list index out of range

Comment: Then you had better provide either the actual traceback or the type of `pacakge_ids` if you want more help.  There is absolutely no "list index" going on in the above code, so if you got such an error doing the above then it must be inside another piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
    for q in range(len(package_ids)):
         if (q==0):
             query = 'Zero' + package_ids[q]
         else:
             query = 'More' + package_ids[q]
```